# Manga where male MC Spins wheel to get reincarnated

Tags: story-identification, manga

In this manga the Main Character (MC) goes to heaven and there is a girl who stands next to a table with a sign that determines which isekai world you will be born in and the MC is very lucky, so the girl who works spinning the roulette wheel finishes her job. and she takes the paper with the name of the world that the MC was born in and leaves saying "my shift was supposed to be over". She doesn't appear again after this.

I don't know what world he was born in.

Comment: Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: Not quite the same thing, but https://myanimelist.net/anime/41380/100-man_no_Inochi_no_Ue_ni_Ore_wa_Tatteiru has the characters spinning a wheel to find their class on each reincarnation.

Comment: this manga is black & white, just somes cover is colored. isnt 100-man, but is good.

Comment: "and she takes the paper with the name of the world that the MC was born in and leaves" Can you elaborate on the importance of taking the paper and leaving? Does this cause problems for his reincarnation? Is she just being a jerk? Or does she end up reincarnating with him, and complains about this?

Comment: to be exact, she just takes the paper with the name of the world on it and leaves the place of reincarnation claiming that she finished her work, but this doesn't bother the MC and she doesn't appear again.

Comment: Is the MC male or female?

Comment: man before and after reincarnation

Answer (score 1):

*[Level 1 Strongest Sage - [Cursed By The Evil God, Can Only Use the Lowest Magic, But Gains Infinite Magic Power by Misunderstanding, and be the Strongest]](https://myanimelist.net/manga/166612/Level_1_no_Saikyou_Kenja__Noroi_de_Saikakyuu_Mahou_shika_Tsukaenai_kedo_Kami_no_Kanchigai_de_Mugen_no_Maryoku_wo_Te_ni_Irete_Saikyou_ni_)*

[image: Front cover of Level 1 Strongest Sage]

> One day, Kijou Haruto was forcefully transmigrated and cursed by a god from another world. A world of swords and magic. In this world you get stronger by increasing your battle levels. But due to a curse, Haruto is unable to gain levels. However, due to a mistake by the Evil God, Haruto was able to obtain an inexhaustable supply of magic...

Is it this one? It's not a roulette wheel, but a dart board.

[image: Evil God throwing at the dartboard to determine Kijou's destination] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

Comment: Not that one but thanks for the recommendation.